# Apache Camel returns NullPointerException when calling CXF Endpoint. This is failing after upgrading camel from 2.X to 3.0

Tags: camel-cxf

I have a CXFEndpoint as below

```
        CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint =new CxfEndpoint();
        cxfEndpoint.setAddress("http://localhost:9201/mock");
        cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.CXF_MESSAGE);
        cxfEndpoint.setWsdlURL(serviceSoapOutboundWsdl);
        cxfEndpoint.setContinuationTimeout(continutionTimeout);
        cxfEndpoint.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(postOutFaultInterceptor);
        .....
        .....
        exchange.setProperty("cxfEndpoint", cxfEndpoint);
```

I call this endpoint from my route builder as below
.toD("${exchangeProperty.cxfEndpoint}")

I am getting following exception

Exception occured while sending outbound message to Receiver::: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: http://localhost:9201/mock. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.acquireProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:139)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:264)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:151)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor$TryState.run(TryProcessor.java:95)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:247)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.ServicePool$SinglePool.acquire(ServicePool.java:234)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.ServicePool$SinglePool.acquire(ServicePool.java:220)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.ServicePool.acquire(ServicePool.java:111)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.acquireProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:112)
... 40 more

I am receiving this error after upgrading camel from 2.X to 3.0. Any inputs to solve this issue will be appreciated.